# Force Symfony doctrine migrations command to use LONGTEXT for json field type instead of JSON when mapping to MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony 4 with a MySQL database (5.5.57-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) that doesn't support JSON type.

When I map a field to "json" using a Doctrine yml config file, the migration file generatet by `doctrine:migrations:diff` uses JSON MySQL type instead of LONGTEXT and it ends up with an error if I try to run the migration.

And every time a make a migration diff, I have to manually change JSON to LONGTEXT for the last changes and remove the changes to JSON as a result of older changes.

It's easy to screw up if in one of these migrations you forget to remove the "ALTER TABLE CHANGE somefield JSON".

My solution, at the moment, is to add in the doctrine.yml config file the following:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
      mapping_types:
           longtext: json
```

It makes some weird, but easy to track and remove, changes when I run `doctrine:migrations:diff -v` , like changing to LONGTEXT some couple of fields that were already LONGTEXT. I don't know why and I have to fix it this eventually.

But, at least, I could stop doctrine from trying to change my longtext to MySQL json data type that are mapped as doctrine json data type.

Did someone came across this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a Doctrine user, but it sounds like you should map the field to "text" instead of "json". This is actually what you're doing if you can't use the `JSON` data type. If you store JSON in LONGTEXT, MySQL won't validate that you're storing correctly formatted JSON. It's just text which might coincidentally be JSON, but you could also store any other text in that field. So it's just text. Declare it as text.

Comment: I get your point, why using json if you can't validate it using real JSON on the database??? and I guess you're right. But I'd like configure that feature for different servers in a doctrine_prod.yml, for instance, if it's possible... but, yes you're right. Doctrine decided to not "lie" developers, if you say json doctrine will use json since it exists in MySQL, if it's not supported by the current version it's your problem. Thanks for your advice ;-)

Comment: Right, I suppose that you shouldn't use the json mapping in Doctrine if you use an old version of MySQL that doesn't support that data type.

Answer (score 2):

I was wrong by using the "mapping_types" configartion that way. It make not sense. The solution It's even more easy, and I didn't realize the following parameter exists:

`server_version`

Just add the server version on the dbal configuration like this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.5.57'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: **NOTE for *MariaDB* users**: don't get confused when setting the `server_version`. – It should **NOT** specify the MySql version (e.g. `5.5.57`) but **MUST** specify the MariaDB version (e.g. `mariadb-10.2.27`). Otherwise you will get sneaky problems with the DBAL (like wrongly generated migrations) even if everything works and there are no errors.

Answer (score 2):

For me i got the same problem and the solution was to go inside the created migration (ex: Version20190306110143.php) and change the dataType "**JSON**" into "**LONGTEXT**"!!

Actually, this worked for me, but frankly, i don't know if this will not cause problems with time. Any way if this happened, i will post them

thanks